# problems with video compilation?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to establish a watermark to the video using ffmpeg and execute commands in a terminal : `ffmpeg -i pic.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex - "overlay=20:20" pic1.mp4`

there is such an error:

**The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.**

*If the video is not available then the sound encoding + overlay watermark is successful, but there is an error with sound*

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? Is `add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.` not clear?

Comment: What @Pekka said. Although I would recommend upgrading to a [recent](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) build. Yours is at least 8 months old.

Comment: pekka I have already written, so there's another bug

Comment: Show full console output.

Comment: Mulvya as well as to establish the fact that I downloaded ?? no sh

Comment: Mulvya Unrecognized option 'strict -2'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

Comment: That is not very helpful without your full command that you used and the complete console output. Without it we can only make guesses, not answers.

Comment: LordNeckbeard at the bottom I wrote the answer, the solution to my problem

Comment: Re-muxing is one of four solutions. The other solutions are to use a modern `ffmpeg` (it does not need `-strict -2` to use the native AAC encoder), or if you want to keep using your outdated `ffmpeg` then add `-strict -2` to your command, or use a different audio encoder.

Answer (score 0):

**agreed**

**ffmpeg -i pic.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex \
"overlay=20:20" -codec:a copy output.flv**